# Install mercusys wifi adapter in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, madwifi

I am trying to install the wifi adapter for the Mercusys mw300uh.

lbusb output:

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2c4e:0104 Realtek  802.11n NIC 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0846:6a00 NetGear, Inc. WG111v2 54 Mbps Wireless [RealTek RTL8187L]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:076d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-5000
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro Usb Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04ca:008e Lite-On Technology Corp. HP USB Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The Mercusys adapter corresponds to :

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2c4e:0104 Realtek  802.11n NIC
```

dkms status

```
8192cu, 1.11, 5.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu, 1.0, 5.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed
```

i have tried several methods on this forum but no luck. I installed the rtl8192eu but it did not work previously. Hope you guys can help me out

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Mercusys(rtl8192eu) as you. I found the solution here:

https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Before you start, I recommend removing the current driver, with the following commands:

```
$ sudo rmmod 8192eu
$ sudo rmmod rtl8xxxu
$ sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/1.0 --all
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is very old, but anybody facing similar issues with WiFi adapter, to the beginners in Ubuntu such as myself, please follow this:

```
lsusb
```

1. This will list all usb connected devices, find your usb in the list, usually has 802.11, Wireless, etc. written on it.
2. Identify its PID/VID, will be something like 0bda:c811, search this on the web and you should find its chipset (or if you're lucky enough, like I was, you'll find another article or solution that will guide you correctly in installing your respective driver).
3. Say you're not lucky enough, then you just google that chipset and search for  driver ubuntu. Ez pz. Took me 2 days to figure it out and had to struggle with a 2GHz adapter until then :'( Peace!

Note: You will have to disable Secure Boot in BIOS, usually clicking F2 on Startup takes you there, then find Boot related section and disable Secure Boot. And you have to reboot for it to work.